# bash program with argument from terminal

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to a run a python program which take a files name and print values in the terminal.My bash program should take three argument from the terminal.First the python program name,second the folder name and third the file name where I want to store the output of my python program.

```
#!/bin/bash
directoryname = "$1"
programname = "$2"
newfilename ="$3"
for file in directoryname
 do
  python3 programname "$file"  >> newfilename
 done
```

and I am executing the program as follows:
./myscript.sh mypython.py /home/data myfile.txt

but it is giving error as :

```
 ./myscript.sh: line 2: directoryname: command not found
 ./myscript.sh: line 3: programname: command not found
 ./myscript.sh: line 4: newfilename: command not found
```

Please help me with this.I am pretty new to bash script.

Comment: Remove the spaces between the variable name and the **=**

Comment: You mean from the command line, right?  You're saying "from the terminal", but to me that would imply prompting and reading a value from after the script has been run.

Comment: Are you wanting to process all the files in the named directory?  If not, why do you have a loop?  If so, you need to add `/*` (and `$`) — as in `$directoryname/*` — to the loop control.

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
#!/bin/bash
directoryname="$1"
programname="$2"
newfilename="$3"
for file in $directoryname
do
      python3 "$programname" "$file"  >> "$newfilename"
done
```

No spaces around the =. A var is tagged with the $ before its name. In general, a var expansion is better if quoted ($var vs "$var").

And, I assume that you do want the list of files inside a directory, but the directoryname is only the directory itself (as /home/user/). If so, you will need:

```
for file in "$directoryname"/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The unnecessary spaces in-between `=` and the variable names and the values are causing the issues, remove the spaces and try again. Will work. :)

```
#!/bin/bash
directoryname="$1"
programname="$2"
newfilename="$3"
for file in directoryname
 do
  python3 programname "$file"  >> newfilename
 done
```

Comment: That's part of the problem, but not the whole problem.

Comment: Okay, i didn't know about the python shell command, but what i was trying to do was to eradicate the errors he mentioned. Thanks.